# bug in System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder.MarkAsSafe and LowerCodeCharts.None?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, antixsslibrary

I did a [Microsoft Connect bug submission](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1070601), I linked this question in my submission.

---

I'm playing around with the `System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder.MarkAsSafe` to test a few things and I found this.

This code, which seem proper:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder.MarkAsSafe
    (
        LowerCodeCharts.None,
        LowerMidCodeCharts.None,
        MidCodeCharts.None,
        UpperMidCodeCharts.None,
        UpperCodeCharts.None
    );

    /*2 randoms characters from each pdf linked below */
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
        System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(
               "%* Ü¼ aW ?? ?? ??", false));

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
        System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(
               "%* Ü¼ aW ?? ?? ??", true));
}
```

Doesn't work like it should. The string above are not being encoded.

It seem that it is still use `LowerCodeCharts.Default`, ignoring my `LowerCodeCharts.None`, which use these(I found the list of each character set [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Security/AntiXss/CodeCharts.cs,fd74fb689f2ab56f)).

[BasicLatin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf), [C1ControlsAndLatin1Supplement](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf), [LatinExtendedA](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0100.pdf), [LatinExtendedB](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0180.pdf), [IpaExtensions](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0250.pdf), [SpacingModifierLetters](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U02B0.pdf), [CombiningDiacriticalMarks](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0300.pdf)

---

so after looking with ILSpy at `System.Web.Security.AntiXss.UnicodeCharacterEncoder`

I found this code;

```
public static void MarkAsSafe(....)
{

if (lowerCodeCharts == UnicodeCharacterEncoder.currentLowerCodeChartSettings && 
    lowerMidCodeCharts == UnicodeCharacterEncoder.currentLowerMidCodeChartSettings && 
    midCodeCharts == UnicodeCharacterEncoder.currentMidCodeChartSettings && 
    upperMidCodeCharts == UnicodeCharacterEncoder.currentUpperMidCodeChartSettings && 
    upperCodeCharts == UnicodeCharacterEncoder.currentUpperCodeChartSettings)
{
    return;
}

  /*actual code that does something*/
}
```

I looked with ILSpy and the default value is `None` for all of them

This make my first attempt of `MarkAsSafe` being void

When I call, with or without my `None`

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
    System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(
           "%* Ü¼ aW ?? ?? ??", false));
```

It goes through, by looking at `System.Web.Security.AntiXss.UnicodeCharacterEncoder` in ILSpy, this

```
private static void InitialiseSafeList()
{
/*some code */
if (UnicodeCharacterEncoder.characterValues == null)
{
    UnicodeCharacterEncoder.InitialiseSafeList();
}
/*some code */
}
```

because `UnicodeCharacterEncoder.characterValues` is null at that point, I verified this with a Watch Window in Visual Studio. The `UnicodeCharacterEncoder.InitialiseSafeList` method as this line

```
SafeList.PunchUnicodeThrough(ref UnicodeCharacterEncoder.characterValues, 
                                 LowerCodeCharts.Default, 
                                 LowerMidCodeCharts.None, 
                                 MidCodeCharts.None, 
                                 UpperMidCodeCharts.None, 
                                 UpperCodeCharts.None);
```

So to make it REALLY `None`, I have tried to call MarkAsSafe twice, one with fake value to make sure it doesn't void it and then a call it with ALL `None`

```
System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder.MarkAsSafe
(
LowerCodeCharts.None,
LowerMidCodeCharts.None,
MidCodeCharts.Arrows,      /*    FAKE VALUE to trigger the proper code */
UpperMidCodeCharts.None,
UpperCodeCharts.None);

System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder.MarkAsSafe
    (
    LowerCodeCharts.None, /*    NOW THIS WORK      */
    LowerMidCodeCharts.None,
    MidCodeCharts.None,
    UpperMidCodeCharts.None,
    UpperCodeCharts.None);
```

now i actually get an encoded string

```
&#37;&#42;&#220;&#188;&#261;&#372;&#419;&#508;&#612;&#681;&#742;&#767;
```

and yet it is impossible to reset the internal array `UnicodeCharacterEncoder.characterValues` so in my example since I used `MidCodeCharts.Arrows`, they are now treated as safe. Impossible to change it back to unsafe.

---

For fun I wanted to find a way to make it work like it should and **this make it work**.

**Please, this code is not for production use. PLEASE!!**

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder));
var type = assembly.GetType("System.Web.Security.AntiXss.UnicodeCharacterEncoder");
var field = type.GetField("currentLowerCodeChartSettings", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
field.SetValue(null, -1);


System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder.MarkAsSafe
(
    System.Web.Security.AntiXss.LowerCodeCharts.None,
    System.Web.Security.AntiXss.LowerMidCodeCharts.None,
    System.Web.Security.AntiXss.MidCodeCharts.None,
    System.Web.Security.AntiXss.UpperMidCodeCharts.None,
    System.Web.Security.AntiXss.UpperCodeCharts.None
);
```

**Please, this code is not for production use. PLEASE!!**

---

So my question is, with the current implementation of the library, is there another way of having all encoding mark as not safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was confirmed as a bug in January and it just [got closed as won't fix](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1070601).

It seem that if your are hit by this bug, you have to use the **NOT RECOMMENDED** code in my question.

Also if you have to change many time at runtime the encoding, you need to find a way to manually reset the internal array. Otherwise the encoding will include any previous "MarkAsSafe" call. This can be done by manipulating private / internal variable which is **NOT RECOMMENDED**.

Comment: Well, that's `static` for you, I guess.